# Spark: Streaming DataFrame

Tags: java, spring, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I wrote a SpringBoot App that can run as Spark Submit job (Never ending job) giving me an endpoint that I can use to get data from SQLContext. I need to stream data as I get from dataframe. I do the following.

**Spring Configuration Class**

```
@Configuration
public class SparkConfiguration {
@Bean
public SparkConf sparkConf(){
    return new SparkConf().setAppName("TestApp").setMaster("local[*]");
}
@Bean
public JavaSparkContext sparkContext(final SparkConf sparkConf){
    return new JavaSparkContext(sparkConf);
}
@Bean
public SQLContext sqlContext(final JavaSparkContext javaSparkContext){
    return new SQLContext(javaSparkContext);
}
```

**Rest Controller Class**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class TestResource {
@Autowired
private SQLContext sqlContext;
@GetMapping
@ResponseBody
public void test(HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse) throws 
IOException {
    DataFrame dataFrame = 
   sqlContext.sql("SELECT * from TABLE_1").toDF();
    PrintWriter writer = httpServletResponse.getWriter();
    dataFrame.collectAsList().forEach(row -> {
        System.out.println(row);
        writer.write(String.valueOf(row.get(0)));
        writer.flush();
    });
    }
}
```

This works fine!!
But this is not really streaming data.
The moment I do, the below.

```
dataFrame.collectAsList()
```

The data get accumulated and then I loop.
Let's say the data is huge (in millions), So I tried to get to the "Row" and push data to writer.

Like this:

```
@GetMapping
@ResponseBody
public void test(HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse) throws IOException {
    DataFrame dataFrame = sqlContext.sql("SELECT * from TABLE_1").toDF();
    PrintWriter writer = httpServletResponse.getWriter();
    dataFrame.javaRDD().map(new Function<Row, Object>() {
        @Override
        public Object call(Row row) throws Exception {
            writer.write(String.valueOf(row.get(0)));
            writer.flush();
            return null;
        }
    }).collect();

}
```

I get Error:

```
INFO  SparkContext - Created broadcast 9 from javaRDD at TestResource.java:38
ERROR [dispatcherServlet] - Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable] with root cause
java.io.NotSerializableException: com.example.TestResource
Serialization stack:
    - object not serializable (class: com.example.TestResource, value: com.example.TestResource@1a8de8c7)
    - field (class: com.example.TestResource$1, name: this$0, type: class com.example.TestResource)
    - object (class com.example.TestResource$1, com.example.TestResource$1@4a0dd65b)
    - field (class: org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaPairRDD$$anonfun$toScalaFunction$1, name: fun$1, type: interface org.apache.spark.api.java.function.Function)
    - object (class org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaPairRDD$$anonfun$toScalaFunction$1, )
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.SerializationDebugger$.improveException(SerializationDebugger.scala:40)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializationStream.writeObject(JavaSerializer.scala:47)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.serialize(JavaSerializer.scala:101)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.ensureSerializable(ClosureCleaner.scala:301)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.org$apache$spark$util$ClosureCleaner$$clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:294)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:122)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.clean(SparkContext.scala:2066)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$map$1.apply(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$map$1.apply(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:150)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:111)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:316)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.map(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDDLike$class.map(JavaRDDLike.scala:96)
    at org.apache.spark.api.java.AbstractJavaRDDLike.map(JavaRDDLike.scala:46)
    at com.example.TestResource.test(TestResource.java:38)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:133)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:116)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:105)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:474)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:783)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:798)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1434)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Any Suggestions, welcome.
Thanks

Comment: I think this is because the object _writer_ from _httpServletResponse.getWriter()_ is not serialized.
Thanks